# Doubt on Lax formulation of Korteweg–de Vries equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, non-linear-systems, integrable-systems, solitons

The [Korteweg–de Vries equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korteweg%E2%80%93de_Vries_equation) is given by:

$$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}-6u\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial^3 u(x,t)}{\partial x^3}=0$$

This equation can be formulated using so called Lax pair. Two linear operators, L and M, form a Lax pair if they satisfy:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}=ML-LM\equiv [M,L]$$

For Korteweg–de Vries equation $L=-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+u(x,t)$. To me it seems that when one takes partial derivative of L, it should act on both parts of L. But the result given in the book (Solitons: An Introduction by Drazin and Johnson) is:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}$$

How is this correct?

Comment: The result is correct, of course. The time derivative of *x* and thus the gradient operator with respect to it vanishes. That's the very point of partial derivatives: you keep the *other* variable fixed. Is there something else you have in mind?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am confused because L may act on function which has time dependence. In that case $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}$ will act on $\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}$, right?

Comment: *x* has no time dependence and thus its gradient doesn't. *x* and *t* are independent variables. *u* depends on both.

Comment: I think I have understood what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to figure out the answer to my own question. I would post it here in case someone has the same doubt. Suppose L acts on a function $\psi(x,t)$. For the following calculation I would not explicitly write the $x,t$ dependence of $\psi$ and $u$
\begin{align*}
L \psi &= -\frac{\partial ^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}+u\psi \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(L \psi)&=-\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}(\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}) + \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\psi+ u \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \\
L\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}\psi&=(-\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}+u) (\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t})+\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\psi \\
L\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}\psi&= L\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\psi \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial t} &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}
\end{align*}